# Rewrite condition in .htaccess not redirecting traffic

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

The images are not showing on our staging environment because we don't have wp_uploads folder.

I received this code for .htaccess that should redirect requests from staging to the live site but I am still getting 404 not found.

[image]

What is wrong with the code?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/uploads/[^\/]*/?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.zeo.nl/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code and it should work as is. Are you sure your server is reading the htaccess rules?

Comment: That's what I thought, but somehow, Laragon is not reading the .htaccess for some reason..

Comment: maybe change the position of above code in your .htaccess file

Comment: I did, didn't help. Also added some random text at the top to break .htaccess but that didn't help. So .htaccess must be disabled somewhere..